# Binding Comboboxes in C# windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, data-binding, combobox

I've got 2 comboboxes that both use the same datasource.
Whenever I change one of the comboboxes the other changes to exactly the same value.

It seems that to solve this problem I need to use databinding.

I've tried lots of things but nothing seems to work.
My comboboxes are named comboBox1 and comboBox2.
Below is the source code I'm trying to use to make combobox2 act independantly of comboBox1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(this.claimTypeBindingSource, null);
    BindingContext bc = new BindingContext();
    comboBox2.BindingContext = bc;
    comboBox2.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ClaimType";
```

EDIT
I've just now taken the dataSource assignments outof comboBox1 and assigned using code - the code now looks like this.

```
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs1 = new BindingSource(this.claimTypeBindingSource, null);
        BindingContext bc1 = new BindingContext();
        comboBox1.BindingContext = bc1;
        comboBox1.DataSource = bs1.DataSource;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ClaimType";

        BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource(this.claimTypeBindingSource, null);
        BindingContext bc2 = new BindingContext();
        comboBox2.BindingContext = bc2;
        comboBox2.DataSource = bs2.DataSource;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ClaimType";
    }
```

This hasn't fixed the problem.
If I change 1 comboBox the other changes as well.

Comment: Can You provide more code - for example how You set same properties for first ComboBox?

Comment: In this example I've just dragged 2 comboBoxes from the toolbox onto the forms designer and added the code above to forms activated method. In combobox1 i've assgned a datasource and DisplayMember via the properties and comboBox 2 is assigned using the above code.

Comment: I've just made a change to my code - unfortunately that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved it :-)
This works - I've put it into my real project and it works perfectly.

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(this.claimTypeBindingSource, null);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ClaimType";

        comboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(this.claimTypeBindingSource, null);
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "ClaimType";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple code that I am using to populate two Combo boxes and 
changing a value from first combo box does not change the value of other.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim data As New List(Of Product)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim bs1 As New BindingSource(data, Nothing)
        Dim bc1 As New BindingContext()
        ComboBox1.BindingContext = bc1
        ComboBox1.DataSource = bs1.DataSource
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "ProductName"

        Dim bs2 As New BindingSource(data, Nothing)
        Dim bc2 As New BindingContext()
        ComboBox2.BindingContext = bc2
        ComboBox2.DataSource = bs2.DataSource
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "ProductName"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        For intCounter As Integer = 1 To 10
            data.Add(New Product(intCounter, intCounter.ToString))
        Next

    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Product

    Public Property ProductID As Integer = 0
    Public Property ProductName As String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(ID As Integer, Name As String)

        Me.ProductID = ID
        Me.ProductName = Name
    End Sub

End Class
```